# Cannot write to csv using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

[image]

```
resource.json
[
  {
    "changedTime": "2021-03-24T18:19:57.158299+00:00",
    "createdTime": "2021-03-24T18:09:56.900636+00:00",
    "id": "/subscriptions/fd7d53ef-e290-4ab1-937e-fec061c00132/resourceGroups/ARO-SANDBOX-GBV6J-RG/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/aro-sandbox-gbv6j-bootstrap_OSDisk",
    "identity": null,
    "kind": null,
    "location": "eastus",
    "managedBy": "/subscriptions/fd7d53ef-e290-4ab1-937e-fec061c00132/resourceGroups/aro-sandbox-gbv6j-rg/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/aro-sandbox-gbv6j-bootstrap",
    "name": "aro-sandbox-gbv6j-bootstrap_OSDisk",
    "plan": null,
    "properties": null,
    "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
    "resourceGroup": "ARO-SANDBOX-GBV6J-RG",
    "sku": {
      "capacity": null,
      "family": null,
      "model": null,
      "name": "Premium_LRS",
      "size": null,
      "tier": "Premium"
    },
users.json
[
  {
    "accountEnabled": true,
    "ageGroup": null,
    "assignedLicenses": [],
    "assignedPlans": [],
    "city": null,
    "companyName": null,
    "consentProvidedForMinor": null,
    "country": null,
    "createdDateTime": "2021-03-25T18:40:48Z",
    "creationType": "Invitation",
    "deletionTimestamp": null,
    "department": null,
    "dirSyncEnabled": null,
    "displayName": "xxx2015",
    "employeeId": null,
    "facsimileTelephoneNumber": null,
    "givenName": null,
    "immutableId": null,
    "isCompromised": null,
    "jobTitle": null,
    "lastDirSyncTime": null,
    "legalAgeGroupClassification": null,
    "mail": "xxx@gmail.com",
    "mailNickname": "xxxgmail.com#EXT#",
    "mobile": null,
    "objectId": "288d8043-73c0-49e4-9360-4e38f0759bae",
    "objectType": "User",
    "odata.type": "Microsoft.DirectoryServices.User",
    "onPremisesDistinguishedName": null,
    "onPremisesSecurityIdentifier": null,
    "otherMails": [
      "xxx@gmail.com"
    ],
    "passwordPolicies": null,
    "passwordProfile": null,
    "physicalDeliveryOfficeName": null,
    "postalCode": null,
    "preferredLanguage": null,
    "provisionedPlans": [],
    "provisioningErrors": [],
    "proxyAddresses": [
      "SMTP:xxx@gmail.com"
    ],
    "refreshTokensValidFromDateTime": "2021-03-25T18:40:48Z",
    "showInAddressList": false,
    "signInNames": [],
    "sipProxyAddress": null,
    "state": null,
    "streetAddress": null,
    "surname": null,
    "telephoneNumber": null,
```

I am reading from two `json` files to write to a csv. The data is of unequal lengths. When the second fucntion runs, it tries to add `headers` where the data in the first column ends and ends up giving error `Cannot insert Access, field already exists`. What would be the correct way to do this?

```
import json
import csv
import pandas as pd
def get_obj():
    header_added = False
    with open('C:\\users.json') as f:
        datas = json.load(f)
        for item in datas:
            for k, v in item.items():
                if k == 'objectId':
                    obj = v
                    dict1 = {'Object ID': obj }
                    with open('Azure.csv', 'a+', encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
                        w = csv.DictWriter(f, dict1.keys())
                        if not header_added:
                           w.writeheader()
                           header_added = True
                        w.writerow(dict1))

def get_resource():
    with open('C:\\resource.json') as g:
        data1 = json.load(g)
        for item1 in data1:
            for k, v in item1.items():
                if k == 'id':
                    u_id = v
                    df1 = pd.read_csv('Azure.csv')
                    df1.insert(1, column='Access', value=u_id)
                    df1.to_csv('Azure.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Please add a sample of both `json` files with expected output.

Comment: Adding sreenshot of data isnot a good way, we can copy the text, not the image

Comment: No images please. Please post it as text. Create a reproducible example so that we can copy your data and work on it.

Comment: @ThePyGuy I was thinking the same thing. let me correct this,Ok. Done.

Comment: If `users` and `resource` are different lengths, how are you determining which `users.objectId` and `resource.id` should be in the same row?

Comment: @tdy There is 1 other column with only a single row. That's what the requirement is. They aren't necessarily mapped to each other row-wise.

Comment: I'm still not totally clear on what your desired output is, but I would suggest loading both jsons as dataframes with `pd.read_json()`, manipulating those dfs to your desired layout, then doing a single `pd.to_excel()` at the end.

Comment: @tdy The desired output is simply this. All objectIds from `users.json` under `ObjectIds`, All access from `resource.json` under `access`, in the same `csv`. That's all.The columns aren't related to each other.. I will try your method. Only problem is it is inside the loop, so don't know how to create the `Dataframe`. Then I can simply merge them and create 1 `csv`